# "Fade in and out" animation does not work

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a piece of code that I wrote in the view controller of Xcode. Before that code, even the button called NEXTTIP works. But now, after adding in the animation, the animation does not come out and the button does not work. Please Help!

```html
    
    @IBAction func nextTip(sender: AnyObject) {
        func hideTip() {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5,
                animations: {
                    self.titleLabel.alpha = 0
                    self.contentLabel.alpha = 0
                    self.imageView.alpha = 0
                },
                completion: { finished in
                    self.showTip
                }
            )
        }

        func showTip() {
            titleLabel.text = "For healthy teeth, don't brush after eating"
            contentLabel.text = "Don't brush your teeth immediately after meals and drinks, especially if they were acidic. Wait 30 to 60 minutes before brushing."
            imageView.image = UIImage(named:"teeth.jpg")
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5,
                                       animations: {
            })
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: I cannot work it out.

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing inside the `nextTip()` function is *defining* two new functions, `hideTip()` and `showTip()`.  You're not actually calling them.  Creating functions inside functions in Swift is a perfectly legal thing to do, but is almost certainly not what you want to do here.  You need to move the definitions for `hideTip()` and `showTip()` outside of the `nextTip(:)` function, so your code would be structured like so:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    func hideTip() {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(...)
        // etc.
    }

    func showTip() {
        // stuff
    }

    @IBAction func nextTip(sender: AnyObject) {
        hideTip()
    }
}
```

Comment: is right, you need to call define your functions outside the IBAction and then call them inside of it.